# How do you set the icon of a Dialog control Java FX/Java 8

Tags: java, javafx, icons, javafx-8

I might be missing something very obvious, but I can't find out how to set the Icon for a Dialog component (ProgressDialog to be more precise). I know how to do that for a Stage:

```
this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon/Logo.png")));
```

But I don't find anything for the Dialog family. And somehow, setting the Stage Icon does not influence the Dialog Icon.

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's an excellent tutorial [here](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-dialogs/) by Marco Jakob, where you can find not only how to use dialogs, but also how to solve your problem.

Both for the new dialogs (in JDK8u40 early versions or with [openjfx-dialogs](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs) with JDK 8u25), or for those in [ControlsFX](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx), in order to set the icon of your dialog, you can use this [solution](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/#custom-icon):

```
Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
stage.getIcons().add(
    new Image(this.getClass().getResource("<image>.png").toString()));
```

This code snippet shows how to use a `ProgressDialog`, from ControlsFX, and set an icon for the dialog:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
        @Override protected Task<Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {
                @Override protected Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                    updateMessage("Message . . .");
                    updateProgress(0, 10);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        Thread.sleep(300);
                        updateProgress(i + 1, 10);
                        updateMessage("Progress " + (i + 1) + " of 10");
                    }
                    updateMessage("End task");
                    return null;
                }
            };
        }
    };

    Button btn = new Button("Start Service");
    btn.setOnAction(e -> {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(service);
        dialog.setTitle("Progress Dialog");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Header message");
        Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(this.getClass().getResource("<image>.png").toString()));
        service.start();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(btn), 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: In addition, I recommend invoking `dialog.initOwner(primaryStage)` before showing the dialog.

Comment: Note that this progress dialog shows up when the service starts, so there's no need to call `dialog.showAndWait()`.

Answer (score 10):

Just Do like this:

```
Alert(AlertType.ERROR, "Erreur de connexion! Verifiez vos Identifiants",FINISH); //Cancel..
setTitle("XNotes FX Erreur");
stage = (Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("indiza/XnotesErrorIdz.png")); // To add an icon
showAndWait();
```

Here is the result

[image]

**My friends, is it computer science that we do? : No, we do crafts
**

Comment: it would be stage.getIcons().add(new Image("indiza/XnotesErrorIdz.png")); // To add an icon

Answer (score 10):

You can easily use the icon of your application for the alert-icon by setting your application-window as owner of the alert box:

```
@FXML
Button buShow;
...

Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "Nice Box.", ButtonType.CLOSE);
alert.initOwner(buShow.getScene().getWindow());   // Alert uses the Windows Icon
alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that I include in my JavaFX projects, simply calling this method and passing the Alert as a parameter will set both the title bar icon and the header graphic.

```
public class Msg {

public void showInfo(String title, String header, String message) {
    Alert alertShowInfo = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    addDialogIconTo(alertShowInfo); //add icon and header graphic
    alertShowInfo.setTitle(title);
    alertShowInfo.setHeaderText(header);
    alertShowInfo.setContentText(message);
    alertShowInfo.showAndWait();
}

//this adds images to Alert
public void addDialogIconTo(Alert alert) {
    // Add custom Image to Dialog's title bar
    final Image APPLICATION_ICON = new Image("icon.png");
    Stage dialogStage = (Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
    dialogStage.getIcons().add(APPLICATION_ICON);

    // Add custom ImageView to Dialog's header pane.        
    final ImageView DIALOG_HEADER_ICON = new ImageView("icon.png");
    DIALOG_HEADER_ICON.setFitHeight(48); // Set size to API recommendation.
    DIALOG_HEADER_ICON.setFitWidth(48);
    alert.getDialogPane().setGraphic(DIALOG_HEADER_ICON);                       
    }
}
```

Then, in whatever class I wish to use the Alert, it will already have the customized icon and header graphic.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Msg msg = new Msg();

        // Alert will now include custom icon and header graphic.
        msg.showInfo("Sucess!", "Program succeeded", "Now exiting program");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just similar to any dialog, instead this is inside a button handler.

```
    Alert alert = new Alert(
        AlertType.WARNING,
        "Alert message here.",
        ButtonType.OK
    );
    alert.initOwner(((Button)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
    alert.setTitle("Alert window title");
    alert.showAndWait();
```