# How to change the icon of a javafx alert box

Tags: java, javafx

How do I change the icon of the alert box of in my javafx application. I know how to do it for my main application/stage itself but the same method doesn't work for the alert.

[Example of alert in javafx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUDM8.png)

Comment: Just to be sure... you want to change alert's window icon or icon displayed next to message?

Comment: @Wortig alert window's icon.

Comment: This should answer your question altough it is for javafx version 8. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976345/how-do-you-set-the-icon-of-a-dialog-control-java-fx-java-8

Comment: please don't add tags that are not needed - it's nothing version specific :)

Comment: @kleopatra sorry. I will take care about that from next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```java
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle("Alert Test");
    alert.setHeaderText("Hello, world!");
    ImageView icon = new ImageView(new Image(String.valueOf(this.getClass().getResource("img/close-on.png"))));
    icon.setFitHeight(48);
    icon.setFitWidth(48);
    alert.getDialogPane().setGraphic(icon);
    alert.show();
}
```

[image]