# Can you set icon to a Javafx Alert box?

Tags: javafx, icons, alert

[image: Alert Box Image]

In this, is there anyway I can change the icon on top left of the alert box?

Comment: An `Alert` is actually a `Dialog`  (`Alert` extends `Dialog`) so this answer applies to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976345/how-do-you-set-the-icon-of-a-dialog-control-java-fx-java-8

Comment: Thanks. This really helped