# Modify window icon alert JavaFX

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm trying to modify the window icon in the bar or even in the top left of the window of an alert dialog on JavaFX.

[image: The windows icon]

And I would like this alert box to appear in another tab that flashes and not merge with my app, like the window for launching an application in admin mode.

[image: Tab]

```java
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.setTitle("Confirmation");
alert.setHeaderText("");
Label label = new Label("Compétence enregistrée                                                                                         ");
label.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: #ffeba7;");
alert.getDialogPane().setContent(label);
Region dialogPane = (Region) alert.getDialogPane();
Image image = new Image("Images\icon_ok2.png");
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

alert.getDialogPane().setGraphic(imageView);
dialogPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.web("#1f2029"), null, null)));
alert.showAndWait();
apCompetences.toFront();
```

Comment: if this is Java, don't tag it with JavaScript. No, the two are not the same

Comment: @Stultuske Ohw sorry this is my very first question ^^'  I'll change it right away

Comment: At least partially a duplicate of [How do you set the icon of a Dialog control Java FX/Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27976345/6395627). You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54705045/6395627) to see how the alert can inherit the icon from its owner. Otherwise, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27983567/6395627) shows how to set an icon just for the alert. And just in case, note that an `Alert` is a `Dialog`.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121991/javafx-application-icon

Comment: I’m curious why you want to do this.  Modal dialogs are paired with their parent windows for good reason:  they are one application, and the dialogs should not have separate places on the task bar.  If you just want to make sure a user sees the alert, [Desktop.requestForeground](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#requestForeground(boolean)) might be what you want.